# Boostrap navbar-default transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with my website. I have used bootstrap for responsive use, and i have a navbar and i would like my background see inside, in transparent.

For the moment i have that : [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8LiC.png)
My background doesn't take all height

And i want [Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm6NU.png)

Do you have an idea ?

html:

```
    <header>
      <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        </div>
       </div>
   </header>
</body>
```

and css:

```
html, body
{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

.navbar
{
    height: 70px;
}
.navbar-default
{
   background-color: transparent;
   border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
   border-radius: 0;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: **Your HTML does not match the CSS**. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is what your looking for.

```
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ftaqk4u6/7/